# how c function visit objective-c property in .mm

Tags: objective-c, c

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *versionLabel;
```

I am trying write like this：

```
void sipmessagecallback(char* pMsg)
{ 
   printf("pMsg=%s\n", pMsg); 
   self.versionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", pMsg]; 
}
```

> error : Use of undeclared identifier 'self'

Comment: all in HHContactViewController.mm file

Comment: 1. Please post the whole interface. 2. Please use code tags. 3. There is no `self` in a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C functions aren't methods, so don't have direct access to instance variables of the class that you are in, including `self`. You could write a C function which would work like this:

```
void sipmessagecallback(char *pMsg, MyClass *self) {
   printf("pMsg=%s\n", pMsg); 
   self.versionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", pMsg];
}
```

Obviously when you call this you need to pass `self` to the function.

Comment: Obviously if he can 1. change the signature of the call back and 2. can pass a `self`, then he can send a message instead of having a function with a `self` argument. This is called the action target pattern and gives him the full strength of dynamic dispatching for no costs.

Comment: Of course message sending can be slow (this is the cost of dynamic dispatching), for some highly optimised code using a function or getting a function pointer can be the solution. Obviously  you want to know that the message send is your bottle neck before making this optimisation.